# HTML comment each line separately, not block comments

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Noob question but I want to be able to quickly comment HTML code using keyboard shortcuts in VS Code. The problem is I get this:

```html
<!-- <div class="whatever">
        <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
        <p>this is code I wrote in HTML</p>
      </div> -->
```

instead of this:

```html
<!-- <div class="whatever"> -->
   <!-- <h1>Hellow World!</h1> -->
   <!-- <p>this is code I wrote in HTML</p> -->
<!-- </div> -->
```

Anyone know a good extension for this in VS Code? Thanks

Julien

Comment: If you want to quickly comment out one line at a time, then comment out one line at a time. There's no two ways about this. Code isn't going to be able to assume you want every line commented out individually when you highlight an entire block to comment out.

Comment: @BoltClock PhpStorm does it like that, maybe there is some setting to do this in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

See this extension written by me, [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments), that will do what you want.

--  or older answer --

1. Select through your text - i.e., from some part of the first line to some part of the last line you want separately commented.  I.e., highlight your block of HTML to comment.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> will put a cursor at the end of each line.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> will comment each line separately.

This only seems necessary for HTML, not JS or SCSS for example.

I suppose if you wanted to reduce keystrokes you could make a macro for steps 2 and 3 combined.